# Map image blinks while adding more layers to it

Tags: java, sqlite, geotools

I have an application in java swing and geotools. I have displayed a map image and trying to add images as layers to it. When it adds layer it blinks and after some time at the call to addLayer function map image and other few layers disappear for some time. How to stop this? I am loging all the information at the same time in SQLite and then to my own customised file.

I have stopped trying refreshing all after addLayer function call. The all process should work smoothly without blinking and disappearing. Please Help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `gt-swing` module is really only intended for simple demonstrations. If you intend to use it in production you should add in off screen buffering to allow "fast" refreshes of the map without rereading all the displayed data.